# CSS UL doesn't have the border on all sides except when height is mentioned

Tags: css

I am practicing the men

myIndex.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myMenu.css"> 
</head>
<body>
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="">5 columns</a></li>
<li><a href="">4 columns</a></li>
<li><a href="">3 columns</a></li>
<li><a href="">1 column</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

myMenu.css

```
#menu {
    list-style:none;
    width:940px;
    margin:30px auto 0px auto;
    height:43px;
    padding:0px 20px 0px 20px;

    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;

    background: #014464;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0272a7, #013953);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#0272a7), to(#013953));

    border: 1px solid #002232;
}
#menu li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
    margin-right:30px;
}
#menu li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

here if height:43px is removed from #menu, then it does not have the wrapping container shape (ie borders with rounded 4 corners) rather one single border at the top is visible. I am not sure why is the behavior so? The Ul already knows the elements within it such as li and a with non zero heights then why is it unable to wrap them?

Thanks in advance for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

After removing the height declaration, you need to add `display:inline-block` to your `#menu {...}` css.

```
#menu {
  list-style:none;
  width:940px;
  margin:30px auto 0px auto;
  padding:0px 20px 0px 20px;   
  display:inline-block;     /* add this line */
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #014464;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0272a7, #013953);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#0272a7), to(#013953));
  border: 1px solid #002232;
}
```

Here is a jsbin to show the results: http://jsbin.com/iwomuw/1/edit.

If you would rather not use `display:inline-block`. Another approach is to use `overflow:auto` which will cause the `ul` element to expand with the `li` tags.

Comment: This seems to be producing good result. What is the reasoning behind inline-block solving the problem?

Comment: @Md.ReazulKarim, the reasoning is that an inline-block element is treated as an in-line element and also behaves like a block element. The elements will be placed on the same line.

Comment: @Md.ReazulKarim, did this work for you? I also edited the answer to give another way to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

**Working fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/UsheC/

Floats remove elements from the normal document flow.

For this reason the height of the floated elements is not considered when calculating the height of the container element.


You can overcome this behavior by having a clearing div after the container element.

```
<ul id="menu" class="clearFix">
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">5 columns</a></li>
    <li><a href="">4 columns</a></li>
    <li><a href="">3 columns</a></li>
    <li><a href="">1 column</a></li>
</ul>
```

/\

```
.clearFix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this instead of `height in #menu`

```
display:block;
overflow:hidden;
```

and remove padding from `li` and give them `height` and `line-height` however you need and
give padding to your `a` link from `left` or `right` 
and its work fine